# Loading .fbx file from URL – Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, three.js, fbx

I worked with this:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx.html

If I replace »[models/fbx/Samba Dancing.fbx](http://models/fbx/Samba%20Dancing.fbx)« with »https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/raw/master/examples/models/fbx/Samba%20Dancing.fbx«, the code stops working.

It's important for me to load the .fbx file from an other webspace. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL does not work because of the CORS policy. Chrome for example reports the following error in the browser console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/raw/master/examples/models/fbx/Samba%20Dancing.fbx' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://render.githubusercontent.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Try it with this URL instead which has the required HTTP header set:

https://threejs.org/examples/models/fbx/Samba%20Dancing.fbx

Comment: Thank you so much!